# Android TCP client can't send data to server

Tags: python, android, server, tcp, client

I'm doing project with beacon.

smartphone(android client) collect rssi nearby beacons and send to python(server)

**< current application's function >**

-> when new beacon signal captured, display beacon's rssi value, Mac address

-> connect with tcp and send to python server in real time (Problem!!)

when using method(send text message to python server) with buttonclickevent,
connecting and sending text message works well.

but when i use method with listview adapter(using ArrayMap),
connecting works well, but can't send rssi.

more detail, infinite loop for waiting data

I think there is a problem between using runOnUiThread and data sending but i'm not sure about it.

**Mainactivity**

```
package midascon.example.scanlist;

import com.hanvitsi.midascon.Beacon;
import com.hanvitsi.midascon.BeaconCallback;
import com.hanvitsi.midascon.MidasApplication;
import com.hanvitsi.midascon.manager.ContextManager;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconCallback, Runnable
{
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100;
    private ContextManager contextManager;
    private BeaconListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); }

        checkPermission();

        contextManager = getMidasApplication().getContextManager();
        contextManager.getBeaconSettings().setMidasScanMode(false);

        adapter = new BeaconListAdapter(getBaseContext()); // Beacon list adapter

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconCallback(int status, Beacon beacon) // add beacon to list when beacon signal captured
    {
        switch (status) {
        case STATUS_CODE_ENTER:
        case STATUS_CODE_UPDATE:
            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.addBeacon(beacon);
            break;

        case STATUS_CODE_EXIT:
            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.removeBeacon(beacon);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        runOnUiThread(this);
    }

    public void checkPermission() // allow permission
    {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (adapter != null)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // call name class setting by AndroidManifest.xml
    public MidasApplication getMidasApplication() {
        return (MidasApplication) getApplication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }

        else {
            if (BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled()) {
                // register callback
                contextManager.setBeaconCallback(this);
                contextManager.startLeScan();
            } else {
                contextManager.stopLeScan();

                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        contextManager.stopLeScan();
    }   
}
```

midas is company that made beacon

**BeaconListAdapter**

public class BeaconListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

```
private int count; //counting beacon

private final ArrayMap<String, Beacon> itemMap = new ArrayMap<String, Beacon>();


private final int padding;
public int CurBeaconHave = 2;

private Handler mHandler;

public int port = 9999;

public int initcnt = 0;
public int stackcnt = 0;
public int serveractivate = 0;
public int praccnt = 0;

public static String Sendrssi = "";
public Socket socket = null;


public BeaconListAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int addBeacon(Beacon beacon) {
    synchronized (itemMap) {
        itemMap.put(beacon.getMac(), beacon);
        count = itemMap.size();
        return count;
    }
}

public int removeBeacon(Beacon beacon) {
    synchronized (itemMap) {
        itemMap.remove(beacon.getMac());
        count = itemMap.size();
        return count;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public Beacon getItem(int position) {
    synchronized (itemMap) {
        return itemMap.valueAt(position);
    }
}

void ToPython() {
    try {
            String tmp = Sendrssi;

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
            out.println(tmp);
            out.flush();
            Log.d("sendrssi ",tmp);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*public void ToPython() {
    try {
        String tmp = Sendrssi;
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

        out.write(tmp);
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();
        Log.d("Sending. Rssi : ", tmp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}*/

void connect() {

    Log.w("state", "connecting..");
    Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            String newip = "192.168.0.4";

            try {

                socket = new Socket(newip, port);
                Log.w("state ", "server connected");
                serveractivate = 1;

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.w("state ", "failed");
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("error :" + e1.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    checkUpdate.start();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public void stopsocket()
{
    try
    {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = null;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        convertView.setTag(textView);
    }

    else
    {
        textView = (TextView) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Beacon item = getItem(position);
    int temprssi = item.getRssi();

    while(serveractivate == 0)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Connect State : ","wait for Server Connect...");
        connect();
    }

    if(serveractivate == 1)
    {
        try {
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    int[] values = BeaconUtils.getAccelerometer(item);
    textView.setText(String.format("[%s]\nMAC : %s\nRssi : %d\n", item.getType() == Beacon.TYPE_MIDAS ? "Midascon" : "Beacon", item.getMac(),temprssi));

    if(count == CurBeaconHave)
    {
        if(stackcnt == CurBeaconHave)
        {
            ToPython();
            stackcnt = 0;
            Sendrssi = "";
        }

        else if(stackcnt != CurBeaconHave)
        {
            Sendrssi = Sendrssi + temprssi + " " ;//+ (temprssi - 3) + " " + (temprssi + 5) + " " + (temprssi - 7) + " ";
            stackcnt++;
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

```
total code line is about 400 line, so i upload code that have problem i think.


thank you for reading and try to solve my problem

if you need another code i'll upload it

Note that i'm not good at english, so you may have difficult with reading and understand. sorry for that :(
```

Comment: `using runOnUiThread` I do not see you using that.

Comment: Post errors, exceptions and stacktraces.

Comment: my mistake. i upload Mainactivity part.  connect and sendata method is part of listadapter

Comment: Before i look into that you schould better tell what goes wrong. `Post errors, exceptions and stacktraces.`

Comment: Are you talking about a bluetooth socket?

Comment: `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy ` Why are you messing around with strict mode? Do away with it. Write a good app from start.

Comment: `runOnUiThread(this);` ? What are you trying to run there?

Comment: - no stacktrace, error and exception. code works, but no data transfer

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation and thank you for your advice

Answer (score -1):

problem solved.
It's not a normal method, so please be patient.

BeaconListadapter in connect method, i use thread.
but i don't use thread in Topython method.
because of this, there's problem with socket information when send data
so i delete thread in connect method and run  and  method
in main thread(i know this is idiot thing)

if you use like me, probably use connect and send data method in one thread